# How to hide background contents of window.open while printing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 12 application and I am integrating the behavior to print report.
I am able to achieve the print on button click which opens a new window, but I am not able to figure out how to achieve below things:

1. Remove background contents on window.open so that the print
   window looks like a normal print window which we see by pressing
   Win+P in our browser.
   [image]
2. Center the print window popup in the screen.
3. Not able to display images in print window. If I add any img tag in html like: `<img src="assets/images/galaxy.png" alt="">`, the image is not getting displayed in the print window. If I comment window.print() and just use window.open(), image is getting displayed

**print.service.ts**

```
  showDialog() {
    const factory =
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PrintReportComponent);

    const dialogComponentRef = factory.create(this.injector);
    dialogComponentRef.instance.title = 'Report';

    dialogComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    //fetch the root DOM element of ModalComponent
    const domElement = (dialogComponentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    const WindowPrt = window.open(
      '',
      '',
      'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto'
    );
    WindowPrt.document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
    WindowPrt.document.body.innerHTML = domElement.outerHTML;
    WindowPrt.document.close();
    WindowPrt.focus();
    WindowPrt.print();
    WindowPrt.close();
  }
```

**stackblitz link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c1ewya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprint.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

In this part :

```
const WindowPrt = window.open(
      '',
      '',
      'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto'
    );
```

You have to remove `'', ''.`
change to :

```
const WindowPrt = window.open(
          'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto'
        );
```

Comment: If I remove '' from widow.open, the print window comes perfectly fine, but it opens in a new tab. I want the print window to open in the same page

Comment: Alright let me try it. I will update my answer soon

Comment: If you leave the target parameter empty it will default to '_blank' which will load it in a new window or tab. Try specify '_self' for replaceing current page.

Comment: @Tommi,  I don't want to replace the current page. I just want to display the print window same like the window which comes when we hit Win+P

Comment: Have you tried using '_self' ? It will replace the window that the print is rendered in, making it a blank page with the print-window attached. Or what are you expecting?

Comment: @Tommi I want to display print window on top of the page, not on new tab or blank page

Comment: @AsifZaidi Ah I see! Then i think bazobehram has the solution you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your strategy at all.
If you will do this, it will work. Please try this example one:

[link-stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-t81zzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Finvoice%2Finvoice.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fprint.service.ts)

I added one dummy image in it and it is displayed.

Good luck ;)

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing without routes...?